# How do you disable the action of a button in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am not sure about how to do this. I am trying to allow it so that when the function "end" happens, the score can no longer increase when button is tapped.

```
@IBAction func Button(_ sender: UIButton) {
    score += 1
}

func end() {
   score += 0
}
```

Comment: Disable the button.

Comment: `score += 0` does nothing - you're trying to increment `score` by zero.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the button

```
func end() {
   yourButton.isEnabled = false 
}
```

Comment: it says "UIButton has no member isEnabled"

Comment: What's the name of your button property?

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: you have to create a IBOutlet for button

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:

- yourButton_Outlet_Name.isEnabled = false
- yourButton_Outlet_Name.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

Make sure to use it on the button outlet, not the UIButton class